# Can't SSH/FTP into new user account in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, users, login, useradd

Created new user from shell script using following command:

```
sudo useradd $1 -p $2 --home /var/www/$1
```

I'm not able to login to FTP or SSH as that user, do i need to add the user to some group for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you entered the password in encrypted form as returned by `crypt` like it is mentioned in the man page of useradd?

Answer (score -1):

Also note the first sentence of the *Description* section of [**useradd**(8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/useradd.8.html):

> **useradd** is a low level utility for adding users.  On Debian, administrators should usually use [**adduser**(8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/adduser.8.html) instead.

It's likely that **adduser**(8) would have done whatever it is that needs doing.

Comment: No, `adduser` has no argument to set the password at all.